# Crystal report for Visual Studio 2008 Caching old rpt file

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've used Visual Studio 2008 to make a desktop application that use cristal report plugin.

I've a very strange problem: I've done some change to .rpt file and copied it into executable folder files.

The old report file is correctly overwritten by new one, but when I launch the application (Windows xp pro sp3) and run Report Viewer form, I get my data displayed into old rpt file! I'm becaming crazy but I don't find a way to remove the suspected cached rpt file.

Any ideas?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It will be still referencing to old report in the temp folder. Delete the Temp files in:

> C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Temp

AppData folder is hidden, so check the option to show hidden files from control panel

Comment: I use windows xp sp3. Maybe I have to check in c\documents&setting\user\... ?

Comment: check out the method described [here](http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/empty-temp-folders)

Comment: Deleted all temp files, problem not solved. Help! :(

Comment: If a delete all .rpt file the report is shown! For sure it is some cached file. But where?

Comment: The rpt file is included into executable one. So the problem is solved. I made a mistake.